# Can not remove child coordinator because transitionCoordinator is nil in navigationController delegate method

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, coordinator-pattern, transition-coordinator

**Brief :**

I have implemented [Soroush's](http://khanlou.com/2017/04/migrating-to-coordinators/) **Coordinators** architecture. Everything works fine except the removing part which is needed to remove previous(child) coordinators.

**Scenario :**

I have two `ViewController` named `HomeViewController` and `MyGroupsViewController`. Each has its own coordinator named `HomeCoordinator` and `MyGroupsCoordinator` respectively.

User taps a button on `HomeViewController` which triggers `gotoMyGroupsTapped` function and gets the user to `MyGroupsViewController`, Then the user taps on another button on `MyGroupsViewController` which get the user back to `HomeViewController` by triggering `gotoHomePage()`.

*Pretty simple! : HomeVC -> MyGroupsVC -> HomeVC*

**But the Problem is :**

`navigationController.transitionCoordinator?` is **nil** in `func navigationController(..., didShow viewController: UIViewController...)` in both coordinators and I can not remove child coordinators in each transition.

Is it correct to set `navigationController.delegate = self` in `start()` func of both coordinators?

Should I use `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false )` in my `backToHomePage()` func? because [Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/175/advanced-coordinator-pattern-tutorial-ios) has only used `pushViewController`.

**My Codes [Simplified Versions]:**

HomeCoordinator.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HomeCoordinator: NSObject,Coordinator,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    weak var parentCoordinator : Coordinator?
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

     func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
         // Transition here is nil
         print(" Transition : ",navigationController.transitionCoordinator)
         guard let fromViewController = navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else {
             print("Unknown fromViewController!")
             return
         }
         // Removing a child coordinator
     }

    func gotoMyGroups (){
         let groupsCoordinator = GroupsCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
         childCoordinators.append(groupsCoordinator)
         groupsCoordinator.parentCoordinator = self
         groupsCoordinator.start()
      }

     func start() {
        let vc = HomeViewController.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.delegate = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
     }
}
```

MyGroupsCoordinator.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyGroupsCoordinator: NSObject,Coordinator,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    weak var parentCoordinator : Coordinator?
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }

     func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
         // Transition here is nil
         print(" Transition : ",navigationController.transitionCoordinator)
         guard let fromViewController = navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else {
             print("Unknown fromViewController!")
             return
         }
         // Removing a child coordinator
     }

     func start() {
        let vc = MyGroupViewController.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.delegate = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
     }
}
```

MyGroupViewController.magik

```
class MyGroupViewController :  UIViewControllerWithCoordinator,UITextFieldDelegate,Storyboarded{

     @IBAction func gotoHomePage(_ sender: Any) {
         if let coord = coordinator as? GroupsCoordinator {
             coord.parentCoordinator?.start()
         }
     }
 }
```

HomeViewController.swift

```
 class HomeViewController: UIViewControllerWithCoordinator,Storyboarded {
     @IBAction func gotoMyGroupsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
         guard let acoordinator = coordinator as? HomeCoordinator else {
             return
         }
         acoordinator.gotoMyGroups()
     }
```

Comment: Did you sort this out? I have similar problem, I found out that when I remove the navigationController.delegate = self from the child coordinator, the removal of the child coordinator is executed and not when the child is set as delegate to the navigationController

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me there is a confusion around Coordinator pattern usage here.

From your expected flow `HomeVC -> MyGroupsVC -> HomeVC`, if you mean in the sense `level1 -> level2 -> level3`, then `GroupsCoordinator` should create a new `HomeCoordinator` instance with its own new `HomeVC`.

So instead of your previous code

```
class MyGroupViewController ... {
    @IBAction func gotoHomePage(_ sender: Any) {
        if let coord = coordinator as? GroupsCoordinator {
            coord.parentCoordinator?.start()
        }
    }
}
```

I would change it to

```
class MyGroupViewController ... {
    @IBAction func gotoHomePage(_ sender: Any) {
        if let coord = coordinator as? GroupsCoordinator {
            coord.goToHome()
        }
    }
}

class MyGroupsCoordinator ... {

    func goToHome() {
        let homeCoordinator = HomeCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
        childCoordinators.append(homeCoordinator)
        groupsCoordinator.parentCoordinator = self
        groupsCoordinator.start()
    }
}
```

This will allow you to create a brand new page as you describe there `HomeVC -> MyGroupsVC -> HomeVC`.

---

*However*, if you meant in this approach `level1 -> level2 -> (back) level1`, then you'll need to terminate `MyGroupsCoordinator` and remove from the parent while navigating back.

As you noticed, to do so, you'll need to use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to be able to be notified when the user navigate back (either pop in code, or with classic back button).

One solution I found is to use a `Router` to handle all this navigation when a `UIViewController` is removed from it to also notify via closures the right coordinator to be removed. You can read more about it [here](https://benoitpasquier.com/coordinator-pattern-navigation-back-button-swift/).

*Hope it helps*